# Kotlin jvm html DOCTYPE

Tags: kotlin

I'm a Java Dynosaur who started using Kotlin the day before.

I found myself coding ...

```
    fun toFile(relativePathAndFileName : String) { // file stream out
        File(relativePathAndFileName).printWriter().use { out ->
            out.appendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>")   // My question: is there a way to do this elegantly
                .appendHTML().html {
                    lang = "en"
```

The output is okay because it adds `<!DOCTYPE>`, but the code `out.appendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>")` feels like a hack to me. How can I make it prettier in a Kotlin way?

Comment: Needs more info: what is this appendHTML, because that's not a std kotlin function. And what exactly do you expect to change to the appendLine stuff? It's a single line written to a file, I don't see much to change to that.

In any case, you don't need to instantiate a printwriter to write to an empty file, just writeText() would do.